# MSSQL 2012 creating CLR triggers for WCF fails

Tags: wcf, triggers, clr, .net-assembly, sql-server-2012

I've created system that uses CLR triggers to connect to WCF server and notify it about changes in DB.
It runs ok on SQL server 2008 R2.
Now im trying to migrate on SQL Server 2012.
To use WCF i need to load SMDiagnostics.dll assembly along the others.
Ive checked that clr is enabled in db , and set trustworthy to be "on", ive disabled WCF debuging, ive checked that SQL server runs under Local System account so there is no problems with permissions.
Now my problem is that when i run following command

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies asms WHERE asms.name = N'SMdiagnostics')
create assembly [SMdiagnostics]
from  'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication        Foundation\SMdiagnostics.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe
go
```

i receive following error

> Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'smdiagnostics,
>   version=3.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089,
>   processorarchitecture=msil.' you are registering is not fully tested
>   in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the
>   future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework,
>   your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server
>   Books Online for more details. Msg 6586, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Assembly 'SMdiagnostics' could not be installed because existing
>   policy would keep it from being used.

SMdiagnostics.dll exists at specified path.
As i understand its some kind of policy in SQL server 2012 or in GAC, however i cant find no policies about SMdiagnostics.
Any ideas how to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: People on MSDN forums pointed out that im trying to load assemblies from .net version 3.0 into SQL server 2012 which supports framework 4.0 or higher. That solved some of the problems, but still i cant load some assemblies that i need to use WCF from CLR triggers. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2012/04/20/sql-server-2012-sqlclr-net-framework-version.aspx

Answer (score 12):

We submitted an issue with Microsoft a month ago on the same problem.  My guess is you are unable to load System.IdentityModel.dll which is a dependency of the System.ServiceModel assembly.  Microsoft has indicated to us that while this worked in SQL 2005 and SQL 2008 that it is a known bug in SQL 2012 and they are not going to fix it till SQL 2014.

The fact that this has not become widely known yet is a bit of a surprise to me except that 2012 is still very new.  But this means that you cannot use what I would say is Microsoft's best practice Interprocess Communication technology within SQL CLR (WCF), note that .NET remoting would be out also because it also uses the ServiceModel assembly.

I am hoping for greater clarification on what they would say we should use instead, I am looking into if there is a way to write a WSE based SQL CLR, but not very excited about the prospect.

I'm quite unhappy about this and hope that others raising their voice will point out that it is a real problem and should be considered unacceptable.

Comment: Has anything happened related to this since 2012? I am still getting the error and it is quite the stumbling block

Answer (score 6):

Nathan Schoenack.
Yes, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2742595 fix problem with System.IdentityModel.dll
but with System.Data.Services.dll i still get Error: CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.Data.Services' failed because assembly 'microsoft.visualbasic.activities.compiler' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. 
Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.
Thanx.

Answer (score 5):

SQL 2012 switched to framework version 4.0.30319. So by default you won't be able to load assemblies from older frameworks.

See [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/sqlnetfx/thread/d304924c-ab87-4a0c-915d-7159bfc3753b) for details.

Unfortunately one also cannot load the System.ServiceModel assembly from framework version 4 because it depends on Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler which is not a pure .NET assembly.

Script:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.ServiceModel]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.ServiceModel.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

I always get the following error:

```
Msg 6544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler' failed because assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. 
Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.
```

Comment: SQL 2012 can load .Net 2.0, .Net 3.0 and .Net 3.5 assemblies just fine.

Comment: Sure, but AFAIK the default policy forbids to load older assemblies. At least this is the case with our installation. Nevertheless I still have the issue with the malformed or not pure assembly.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Can anyone tell me HOW to load an earlier version?  I'm getting: "Assembly 'X' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used."

Answer (score 1):

The issue with failing to CREATE ASSEMBLY for System.IdentityModel.dll for .NET framework 4.0 version in SQL Server 2012 has been resolved with a security hotfix recently released by .NET team.

MS13-004: Description of the security update for the .NET Framework 4 on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008 R2: January 8, 2013
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2742595

My testing has shown that there is no issue on CREATE ASSEMBLY with .NET 4.5 assembly of System.IdentityModel.dll in SQL Server 2012.

Nathan Schoenack
SQL Support Technical Lead

Comment: My server says that the KB can't be installed (I tried all 3 flavours, just in case).

How did you manage to import the .Net 4.5 assemblies? My SQL keeps on telling me "... __you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment__ ...".