# Assembly could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used

Tags: c#, windows-7, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012

While attempting to load an earlier version of a .NET assembly, indicated as possible in a comment on an answer to [MSSQL 2012 creating CLR triggers for WCF fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502543/mssql-2012-creating-clr-triggers-for-wcf-fails). I receive the titular error message.

Despite searching for additional information on the error itself, ensuring that 3.5 was installed in Windows Features, investigating useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy and more, I have been unable to determine how to enable previous versions of .NET assemblies to execute in SQL Server 2012 on Server 2012.

Does anyone know what is required to allow this execution?

Comment: Hello, have you solved the question? If yes, could you share the solution?

Comment: @Boogier Unfortunately we were forced to resort to an NTLM WebClient request; using `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity`, `WindowsImpersonationContext`, and the `CredentialCache`.  If you are interested I can post sample code here.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the following SO post and see if that is applicable to your issue:

[SQLCLR using the wrong version of the .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781624/sqlclr-using-the-wrong-version-of-the-net-framework)

Comment: I'll have to try out the accepted answer later this week.  The registry key is not set on the system in question.

Comment: Unfortunately the sqlservr.exe.config suggestion also failed to allow the dlls to be registered.